# Wordpress Blog Posts in Hybris

Tags: wordpress, security, sap-commerce-cloud

My job is developing on Hybris, an SAP eCommerce CMS solution. However they want a Wordpress blog with the ability to have the latest 3 post automatically fed into the Hybris site.

Functionality wise the site would only display the image associate with the blog, and the title of the blog with a read more link that directs the user to the blog entry (and blog site) in question.

Some security concerns have been raised though in terms of how to get the blog fed into Hybris safely.

My developer specifically asked me to ask you guys ***"How do we get data from WP synchronously in batch mode to implement into Hybris? And which API's, protocols, or ways to implement are available?"M6962onerb*

The more I can take back, the more knowledgeable the team will be at getting this past the security team, so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Use rss feed maybe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would :

- Use the wordpress REST API (https://wordpress.org/plugins/json-rest-api/)
- Create a extension on Hybris with :

  - A service to fetch the last 3 posts from Wordpress and save it into Hybris database / memory
  - A cronjob to call the service every hour
  - A facade to get the 3 posts from your controller

*Some security concerns have been raised though in terms of how to get the blog fed into Hybris safely.* Wordpress API needs to be secured (HTTPS and IP access restriction).